# Using div to redirect to php script

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

i have this div that i am using as a sort of button, most of the time, i just use it to redirect to another page, but this time, i want it to run some php before it redirects to the next page.

```
<div class="build_detail_option_ele_wrap" onclick="location.href="builders_checkout.php";"></div>
```

Could i just make it redirect to builders_checkout.php, which creates some sessions etc... and then from there redirect to the end page.

(I know i could do this easier through using a submit button instead, but circumstances mean i can't use one here. )

Is this a good idea, or are there negatives to doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a simple `<a href="">` tag? It has been used for the past 20 years and it's still awesome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one has actually given the (obvious) solution:

```
<a class="build_detail_option_ele_wrap" href="builders_checkout.php"></a>
```

Add this to your CSS, and it won't be visibly different:

```
a.build_detail_option_ele_wrap {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing "wrong" with it, but you'd have better results if you used an `<a href="...">` tag (optionally, set `style="display:block"` to make it behave like a `<div>`).

If you are insistant on a `<div>`, use single quotes around the `builders_checkout.php` string.

Answer (score 2):

Pass a querystring on your url containing the page you should redirect after that script. I used **next**.

```
 ... builders_checkout.php?next=lol_page.php ...
```

In your `builders_checkout.php`, use something like this in the end of your script:

```
// if next is set, we will redirect it to next value (lol_page.php);
if(isset($_GET['next'])){
     header('Location: ' . $_GET['next']);
}
```

If you any question or problem to understand that, just ask.

Answer (score 1):

Well, implement it using jQuery (or even plain JS) instead of `onclick=""`. And of course, uses an `<a href="">` instead of div

So far, there's no problem. Just make sure to let the user know that it's processing with a loading bar.

Comment: Erm, FYI `onclick` is JavaScript inside an HTML attribute.

Comment: @Kolink It is, but it's ugly (spaghetti).

Answer (score 1):

Would you are suggesting doing should work fine, however you need to change the double-quotes inside the `onclick` declration to single quotes like this:

```
<div class="build_detail_option_ele_wrap" onclick="location.href='builders_checkout.php';"></div>
```

If you want to get more advanced, you could look at using AJAX methods to send the data you need to the PHP script and then redirect only if you have success in doing whatever that script needs to do (or even have that script return a string indicating where the browser should be redirected to).

Answer (score 1):

If I am right in what I think you're asking, you might want to consider using AJAX.

jQuery makes this easy:

```
$(".build_detail_option_ele_wrap").on('click', function () {
    // Do your $_SESSION (or other) stuff
    $.get('builders_checkout.php', function () {
        // after the $.get has completed:
        window.location.href = 'lol_page.php';
    })
});
```

Your DIV:

```
 <div class="build_detail_option_ele_wrap"></div>
```

This way, you run "builders_checkout.php" asynchronously, then load the "lol_page.php" URL without having to redirect twice.